# How to send a json file via post, using ajax to a java spring controller where i am consuming an api

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

I've been trying to send a json file, via post from ajax to my controller where i am consuming an api, but i cant get an answer

this is my script where i have my jsonObjects

```
var jsonObjects = {
        "vehicle": {
            "id": "272",
            "year": "2017",
            "marketValue": {
                "amount": 345000,
                "currency": "MXN"
            }
        },
        "downPayment": {
            "amount": 34500,
            "currency": "MXN"
        },
        "installmentPlanTerms": {
            "number": "36",
            "frequency": "MONTHLY"
        },
        "casualtyInsurance": true,
        "lifeInsurance": false
    };
```

this is my ajax where i am including the url of my controller

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/vehicle/cotizar',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObjects),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
       //document.log(data.data.requestedAmount.amount);
    }
});
```

this is my controller in java spring

```
@RequestMapping(value="/vehicle/cotizar")
    public String options(){
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        String token = "some key";
        headers.set("Authorization","jwt ".concat(token));
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        return restTemplate.exchange("https://apis.bbvabancomer.com/loans_sbx/v1/options-installment", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class).getBody();
    }
```

i hope that the controller return me the json result that i did via ajax
[as you can see in the image i am using postman where i am sending a json file via post to api and the api return me an answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ViCa.png)

Comment: You do not need this: `JSON.stringify(jsonObjects)`. Only `jsonObjects` should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved it 
in my controller I had to modify this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/vehicle/cotizar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String performLogin(@RequestBody String json, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    log.info("debugeo".concat(json));
    String token ="some key";
    headers.set("Authorization","jwt ".concat(token));
    //headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    String a ="Content-Type";
    String b = "application/json";
    headers.set(a,b);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(json,headers);
    log.info("con entity prueba".concat(entity.getBody()));
    return restTemplate.exchange("https://apis.bbvabancomer.com/loans_sbx/v1/options-installment", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class).getBody();
}
```

and I get the answer back 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vky7e.png)